# Did the 'Force for Change' competition winner actually appear in Solo: A Star Wars Story?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

Force for Change is a charity beneficiary that asks fans to donate money for various good causes. Often, there are prizes that comes with donating. In 2017, while *Solo: A Star Wars Story* was still in production, fans had a chance to donate and win the ability to appear in the film. However, this was before the whole director change debacle. I was wondering if a winner was announced and if that winner actually appeared in the film, given the fact that seemingly 90% of the film was reshot.

Comment: They cut the Omaze winner from Star Trek; https://blog.omaze.com/star-trek-to-boldly-go-winner-recap/

Comment: For the record, I don't think it was 90% reshot. It was (according to some sources) more like 70%; https://www.indiewire.com/2018/05/solo-star-wars-ron-howard-reshoots-amount-1201962730/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The winner was [revealed](https://blog.omaze.com/winner-reveal-star-wars/) as Jeremy R of Annapolis, Maryland.

I've seen no evidence that his walk-on part was/wasn't cut from the completed film but for the record, the prize didn't include a *guarantee* that the winner would get to walk-on, merely that they would receive a VIP set-tour and a chance to meet the director as well as the *possibility* of an on-screen background role.

> "one VIP tour of the Set Location; double occupancy hotel
> accommodations at a hotel selected by Sponsor in its sole discretion
> close to the Set Location for two consecutive nights; transfers
> to/from hotel and airport; meet and greet with the directors of the
> Movie; the opportunity for the Winner to be filmed (non-speaking) in a
> scene for the Movie; and a chance for the Footage to appear in the
> Movie. Sponsor and Prize Providers do not guarantee that the Footage
> will be included in the final version of the Movie."
>
> <sub><sup>[Omaze: Competition Terms and Conditions](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nTQZ4loQiZgJ:https://www.omaze.com/starwars%20&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)</sup></sub>

This presumably means that if your tour happened to be on a day when they were filming shots inside the Falcon with just the principal cast, there wouldn't be any walk-on parts that you could take.